# Can 'the they self' help us understand Nietzsche's response to nihilism?

Tags: nietzsche, heidegger, nihilism

Can 'das man' or 'the they self' help us understand Nietzsche's response to nihilism? I'm asking because these are concepts I think I can intuitively grasp from within my life, quite unlike Nietzsche's theory of types (even if anyone living fits). And I want to stop my nihilistic despair.

So I have two questions:

1. Can we say that being lost in the meaninglessness of the they self, rather than some other meaninglessness, is a defective response to nihilism?
2. Are Heidegger's lectures on Nietzsche considered good, and what might prep me for reading them?

---

By the [they self](http://faculty.washington.edu/ckeyt/heidlst/heid2.htm), broadly speaking I mean petty conformism, especially when not able to make choices for yourself, so that we are "lost" in others. Their "meaninglessness" would perhaps be one that covers up its reasons, like it does my own death.

e.g.

> In one's concern with...the Others, there is constant care as to the
>   way one differs from them, whether that difference is merely one that
>   is to be evened out, whether [one = Dasein] has lagged behind the
>   Others and wants to catch up in relationship to them, or whether one's
>   Dasein [self] already has some priority over them and sets out to keep
>   them suppressed.

Comment: I think you mean "thyself" instead of "they self"

Comment: @Not_Here what, what do you mean? really? doesn't it just mean das man?

Comment: @Not_Here ah well sorry if i've offended you. i'm not claiming i'm authentic, i can't separate out the difference between morbid fascination with death from freedom for it. but yeah, makes more sense to me than nietzsche!

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with the topic of your question or answering or interpreting what you're asking, I was pointing out what I thought was a spelling error. If "das man" has to do with "they" as in third person plural, then the phrase you're looking for is "themselves" not "they self". I had only seen "das man" translated as "the one" so I thought you meant "thy" instead of "they" but if you mean to say "they self" then the correct way to say that is "themselves", that's all I'm saying.

Comment: ah ok thought it was standard H. terminology http://faculty.washington.edu/ckeyt/heidlst/heid2.htm

Comment: English has no equivalent to the German pronoun 'man'.  The pronoun 'one' is a more common translation than 'they', but 'the one' in English generally uses one as a nominalized adjective rather than a pronoun, which is kind of the opposite of what you want.  So you may need to elaborate here, or you may get a lot of nonsense in response.  A link in a comment probably won't do.

Comment: @jobermark what a strange request. which incidentally reminds me of a therapist i had... i insisted i felt like my life had no meaning, and didn't want to use pseudo technical terms. well, knew, really. yet i explained it perfectly, to a friend, over a beer

Comment: 1) 'You may need to' does not usually make a request.  2) I do not find this observation strange.  3) 'The they self' is clearly a pseudo-technical term.

Comment: @jobermark it's not my pseudo technical term! i don't want to argue about whatever else you want to argue about, however. i mean obviously how am i going to trivially prove that those watching over me aren't happy or whatever it is.

Comment: @jobermark sorry if i seem hostile in tone, just trying to make things clear

Comment: No, I just didn't understand the objection.  Jargon seems inescapable here, all available translations are equally un-apt.  And the jargon could use some grounding.  I would at least move the link from the comment into the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64325/discussion-between-user3293056-and-jobermark).